# Numpy genfromtxt read cell with multiple values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a data file that contains several parameters, some of these parameters are color values, which are in RGB format, i.e. in each color cell there is the array (R,G,B).

The rest of the cells contain a single value, this results in the error

```
Line #11175 (got 38 columns instead of 47)
```

This is a sample of the data file (each value is separated with a tab):

```
RightValidity   Vergence    FixationDist    EventTimeStamp  EventName   EventType   EventId Code    Parameters  Value for trial 1   Value for trial 2   Value for trial 3
4   3.5522  0.613   1537.011    InputEvent  Mouse_DW    2   999 aperture yes/no 1   1   1
4   3.5522  0.613   1736.592    InputEvent  Mouse_UP    2   999 aperture color  (0.8, 0.8, 0.8) (0.8, 0.8, 0.8) (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
4   3.5522  0.613   1752.87 TrialEvent  0   START   8   aperture division   3   3   3
```

And I read the data calling `data = np.genfromtxt(file)`, where file is the data above.

How can I solve this? Is there a way to read an array from a cell?

Comment: it would help if you posted the **actual** data and **code** so that others can *try* to reproduce your error

Comment: Look up questions about reading quoted strings with blanks. Try , for example ,the python `csv` reader with `()` as `quotes`.  Or preprocess the line to convert the offending string into something `genfromtxt` can handle as a string value.

Comment: You have 2 issues - reading the same number of columns in each row, and storing the same kind of values in those last three data fields.  What `dtype` do you want?

Comment: what happens with `data=np.genfromtxt(file, delimiter='\t',dtype=None)`?  If fields are separated by tabs, and there aren't any tabs in `(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)`, you shouldn't get the column count problem.

Comment: Could you give us a sample that is not space or tab delimited?  Tabs aren't preserved, so it is hard to distinguish between delimiters and spaces within strings or variables.  I was going to test your sample, but gave up trying to locate the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes little sense to store your data as a `numpy` `array` are you have mixed datatypes, not only among columns, but also within some columns. `pandas` `dataframe` is naturally more suitable for this type of thing:

The only step required, beyond a simple `read_csv`, is just to convert the tuples that are read as strings back to tuples using a `.map(eval)`:

```
In [20]:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('temp.txt', sep='\t')
In [21]:

print df
   RightValidity  Vergence  FixationDist EventTimeStamp EventName EventType  \
4         3.5522     0.613      1537.011     InputEvent  Mouse_DW         2   
4         3.5522     0.613      1736.592     InputEvent  Mouse_UP         2   
4         3.5522     0.613      1752.870     TrialEvent         0     START   

   EventId Code         Parameters Value for trial 1 Value for trial 2  \
4           999    aperture yes/no                 1                 1   
4           999     aperture color   (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)   
4             8  aperture division                 3                 3   

  Value for trial 3  
4                 1  
4   (0.8, 0.8, 0.8)  
4                 3  
In [22]:

df['Value for trial 1'].values #data not stored in tuples
Out[22]:
array(['1', '(0.8, 0.8, 0.8)', '3'], dtype=object)
In [24]:

df['Value for trial 1'].map(eval).values #so we convert the tuples to tuples, leave numerical numbre unchanged
Out[24]:
array([1, (0.8, 0.8, 0.8), 3], dtype=object)
In [25]:

df['Value for trial 1'] = df['Value for trial 1'].map(eval)
df['Value for trial 2'] = df['Value for trial 2'].map(eval)
df['Value for trial 3'] = df['Value for trial 3'].map(eval)
```